# Perl and Xpath: considering hierarchy

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-parsing, hierarchy

I would like to extract the attribute values of an XML considering the hierarchy level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database>
  <row1s>
   <row1 name="fox" category="mammal">
       <row2s>
         <row2 type="1"/>
         <row2 type="2"/>
       </row2s>
   </row1>
   <row1 name="horse" category="mammal">
       <row2s>
         <row2 type="3"/>
       </row2s>
   </row1>
   <row1 name="bee" category="insect"> 
       <row2s/>
   </row1>
   <row1 name="wasp" category="insect">
       <row2s/>
   </row1>
  </row1s>
</database>
```

This is the Perl-code I extract the values:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xrow1;
my $xrow2;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new (filename => "animals3.xml");

my $node_list1 = $xp->find ("//row1s/row1");

foreach my $row1 ($node_list1->get_nodelist ())  {
    $xrow1 = $row1->getAttribute("name");
    print "Level row1 gives: $xrow1\n";

    my $node_list2 = $xp->find ("//row2s/row2");

    foreach my $row2 ($node_list2->get_nodelist ()) {
    $xrow2 = $row2->getAttribute("type");    
    print "Level row2 gives: $xrow2\n";
    }
}
```

What I get is:

```
Level row1 gives: fox   
Level row2 gives: 1   
Level row2 gives: 2   
Level row2 gives: 3   
Level row1 gives: horse   
Level row2 gives: 1   
Level row2 gives: 2   
Level row2 gives: 3   
Level row1 gives: bee   
Level row2 gives: 1   
Level row2 gives: 2   
Level row2 gives: 3   
Level row1 gives: wasp   
Level row2 gives: 1   
Level row2 gives: 2   
Level row2 gives: 3
```

For each level 1 I get all attribute values from level 2. This is not that what i want. I would like to output only the the level 2 entries of the correpondent level 1. But what I want is:

```
Level row1 gives: fox   
Level row2 gives: 1   
Level row2 gives: 2   
Level row1 gives: horse   
Level row2 gives: 3   
Level row1 gives: bee   
Level row1 gives: wasp
```

I would appreciate any hint how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A leading `/` indicates an absolute path.

```
my $node2 = $xp->find("//row2s/row2");
```

should be

```
my $node2 = $xp->find("row2s/row2", $row1);
```

---

Comments:

- Neither `$node1` nor `$node2` are nodes. Pick better names.
- Declaring your variables where you did partially defies the purpose of declaring them. they should be declared within the appropriate loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I changed the line as you suggested. The output gives now only the attribute values from level 1 (fox, horse, bee, wasp) without correspondent level 2 values. If $node1 is not a node what is it? Would be $element1 better? or $level1?

Comment: `$node1_list` or `$animals` are two possibilities. Testing

Comment: oh, it's cause your XML makes no sense. Despite your indenting implying otherwise, none of the `row1` elements have a `row2s` child. I think you meant to use `<row1 name="fox" category="mammal"><row2s><row2 type="1"/><row2 type="2"/></row2s></row1>` Are you ok with fixing up the XML, or do you need code that works with what you have?

Comment: That's it. You're right. The xml was wrong and I corrected as you mentioned and as it was supposed to be. Now it works. Thank you very much for your help. It was really important for me. I wonder where I can gather these kind of informtion. Another question: which variable should be declared into the loops?

Comment: `$xrow1` and `$xrow2`.

Comment: Re "I wonder where I can gather these kind of informtion", I learned XPaths by reading the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). As specs go, it's quite light. Still, that might not be for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The following fixes and simplifies your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

#my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => "animals3.xml" );
my $xp = XML::XPath->new( ioref => \*DATA );

for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('//row1s/row1') ){
    printf "Level row1 gives: %s\n", $row1->getAttribute("name");

    for my $row2 ( $row1->findnodes('.//row2s/row2') ) {
        printf "Level row2 gives: %s\n", $row2->getAttribute("type");
    }
}

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database>
  <row1s>
   <row1 name="fox" category="mammal">
       <row2s>
         <row2 type="1"/>
         <row2 type="2"/>
       </row2s>
   </row1>
   <row1 name="horse" category="mammal">
       <row2s>
         <row2 type="3"/>
       </row2s>
   </row1>
   <row1 name="bee" category="insect"> 
       <row2s/>
   </row1>
   <row1 name="wasp" category="insect">
       <row2s/>
   </row1>
  </row1s>
</database>
```

Outputs:

```
Level row1 gives: fox
Level row2 gives: 1
Level row2 gives: 2
Level row1 gives: horse
Level row2 gives: 3
Level row1 gives: bee
Level row1 gives: wasp
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I learned some new tricks. I would very appreciate if you would have a look at my follow up question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702607/perl-and-xpath-missing-entries-in-database-table).

Comment: Glad I could help.  I took a look at your new question but I see that Borodin has already done a sufficient job in helping.